# How to create and assign events to dynamically loaded gui?

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-events

I'm trying to create a WPF application where the users are allowed to create a custom gui dynamically loaded with some xaml files.

There are two files needed for this to happen:

The main xaml file which contains the gui elements

```
<Grid>
    <Button Name="button1" Height="82" Width="132">Button Text</Button>
    <TextBlock Text="Text Data"/>
</Grid>
```

and the events file with the events:

```
<Events>
    <Event Object="button1" Event="Click" File="button1OnClick"/>
</Events>
```

I load the files correct and the gui is shown but the events (in this example the button click event) are not triggered. I tried it with this code (and some varieties of it):

```
/*
scroll = parent object of the custom gui (ScrollViewer)
events = List of the events in the events file
evnt.Event == "Click"
evnt.ObjectName == "button1"
evnt.File == "button1OnClick"
*/

List<DependencyObject> childs = scroll.GetLogicalChilds();
foreach (DependencyObject control in childs)
{
    Control c = null;
    if(control is DependencyObject)
        c = control as Control;

    if (c == null)
        continue;

    foreach(PluginEvent evnt in events)
    {
        if (evnt.ObjectName == c.Name) //button1 == button1
        {
            RoutedEvent routedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
                evnt.Event,
                RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
                typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
                c.GetType());

            Action handler = () => Lua.DoFile(evnt.File + ".lua");
            c.AddHandler(routedEvent, handler);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example I try to run the `button1OnClick.lua` file when I click on the button named `button1` but I get an error

> Handler type is mismatched.

and I don't know how to fix this. Can somebody explain me how to run the lua file when the event is triggered?

The target is to run the the file which is declared inside the events file when the event is triggered.

**Edit1:**
I fixed the exception with this code

```
RoutedEvent routedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(evnt.Event, RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), c.GetType());
RoutedEventHandler handler = (s, a) => Lua.DoFile(evnt.File + ".lua");

c.AddHandler(routedEvent, handler);
```

but it don't trigger if i click the button

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
Action handler = () => Lua.DoFile(evnt.File + ".lua");
c.AddHandler(routedEvent, handler);
```

To more *appropriate* event handler

```
c.AddHandler(routedEvent, (delegate)(s, o) => Lua.DoFile(evnt.File + ".lua")); // not sure
```

Based on your comment (^^):

```
Action<object,RoutedEventHandler> handler = (s, o) => Lua.DoFile(evnt.File + ".lua");
c.AddHandler(routedEvent, handler);
```

Comment: this will not work because lambda expressions aren't allowed :( it must be a delegate and `Action<object, RoutedEventHandler> handler = (s, o) => { LuaHelper.DoFile(evnt.File); };` do not work either. i get the same exception :(

Comment: no. i can't convert a lambda expression to a delegate like this. that's why i use `Action<>` for this. but i tried it anyway and it didn't work.

Comment: You are better programmer when it comes to fix your mistakes, than I am =P